# undefined is not a function error on javascript load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been trying to debug this issue for the past 3 hours and pulling my hair now. In my site when I load I get a undefined is not a function. I've been looking at the syntax and nothing seems to be wrong. Here is a link to my [site](http://seller.shopious.com/). If you check the console, then it errors on the first load. Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your plugin "Lazy Load" does not terminate with a semi colon, and as such cannot be combined into a single file with "malihu jquery custom scrollbars".

As the second plugin starts with `(`, the javascript engine will interpret that as a call to a function that it expects to be returned from the previous function call.

Add a `;` at the end of the Lazy Load file.

Roughly, the code

```
/*
 * Lazy Load - jQuery plugin for lazy loading images
 */

(function(a,b,c,d){ .... })(jQuery,window,document)

/* 
== malihu jquery custom scrollbars plugin == 
*/
(function($){ ...})(jQuery);
```

is interpreted as

```
anonymousFunction(jQuery, window, document)(function($) { ... })
                                           ^ anonymous function returns undefined
                                             but a function was expected
```

Comment: this is weird.. I added a ; at the end of the lazy load file, but it didn't help..

Comment: @adit: A browser cache issue perhaps? I no longer see the errors when visiting the site.